# Keras multiclass classification predicts always the same label

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to train a model to predict one's emotion from the physical signals. I have three physical signals and using it as input features;

> ecg(Electrocardiography), gsr(galvanic skin response),  temp(temparature)

In my dataset, there are **312** total records belonging to the participants and there are **18000** rows of data in each record. So when I combine them into a single data frame, there are **5616000** rows in total.

Here is my `x_train` dataframe;

```
           ecg     gsr   temp
0        0.1912  0.0000  40.10
1        0.3597  0.0000  40.26
2        0.3597  0.0000  40.20
3        0.3597  0.0000  40.20
4        0.3597  0.0000  40.33
5        0.3597  0.0000  40.03
6        0.2739  0.0039  40.13
7        0.1641  0.0031  40.20
8        0.0776  0.0025  40.20
9        0.0005  0.0020  40.26
10      -0.0375  0.0016  40.03
11      -0.0676  0.0013  40.16
12      -0.1071  0.0010  40.20
13      -0.1197  0.0047  40.20
..      .......  ......  .....
..      .......  ......  .....
..      .......  ......  .....
5616000 0.0226  0.1803  38.43
```

And I have 6 classes which are corresponding to emotions. I have encoded these labels with numbers;

> anger = 0, calmness = 1, disgust = 2, fear = 3, happiness = 4, sadness = 5

Here is my y_train;

```
         emotion
0              0
1              0
2              0
3              0
4              0
.              .
.              .
.              .
18001          1
18002          1
18003          1
.              .
.              .
.              .
360001         2
360002         2
360003         2
.              .
.              .
.              .
.              .
5616000        5
```

To feed my CNN, I am reshaping the train_x and one hot encoding the train_y data.

```
train_x = train_x.values.reshape(312,18000,3) #because I have 18000 rows in each record and 3 input features
train_y = train_y.values.reshape(312,18000)

trunc_train_y = train_y[:,:1] # to get 1 label for every 18000 column vector of signal
train_y_enc = pd.DataFrame(trunc_train_y) 
train_y_enc = pd.get_dummies(train_y_enc[0]) # one hot encoded labels
```

After reshaping, I have created my CNN model;

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(2,700,activation='relu',input_shape=(18000,3)))
model.add(Conv1D(2,700,activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(4))
model.add(Conv1D(2,700,activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv1D(2,700,activation='relu'))
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling1D())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(6,activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer = sgd, loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['acc'])
model.fit(train_x,train_y_enc,epochs = 300, batch_size = 32, validation_split=0.33, shuffle=False)
```

The problem is, accuracy is not going more than 0.2 and when I check the predictions, it is always predicting the same class. I have tried to **increase layers**, **play with the learning rate**, **changing the loss function**, **changing the optimizer** but nothing helped me to solve this problem.

Here is the confusion matrix;

[image]

How Can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your handling of data looks very strange. I think it should be `(train_sample_length, num_features)`. Also, why is your `train_y` of the shape `(312,18000)`? It should be `(train_sample_length, num_classes).` I can see in your case `num_features=3` and `num_classes=5`.

Comment: @Anakin, because I have 312 different records in total. I am transposing the signals so that every signal sequence corresponds to a single row. So in every row, there is 18006 columns ( signal lenght + one hot encoded labels). I am doing the transpose operation because I don't want to label every millisecond of the signal, it is better to transpose it and label only once.

Comment: Got the 312 part. Maybe you should consider the entire 5616000 rows and shuffle the data and split into training and validation

Comment: @Anakin, If I am going the shuffle it in the form with 5616000 rows, then all the signal structure would be breaken.

Comment: Maybe I got your problem wrong. Okay, tell me: for prediction, do you want to input a 3d vector  `[ecg     gsr   temp]` and predict the `emotion`?

Comment: Let's speak only with the `ecg` signal for simplicity. I want to input `[ecg]` as input and ecg looks like this; `[ 0.712  0.855  0.942 ......... 0.125]` with the lenght of 18000(a column vector). The classification I want is on the `emotion`.

Comment: Yes. And you have an `emotion` label across each of those 18000 values. Right? I mean to ask...are you training on sequential data or just independent observation values?

Comment: 1) Are the classes very imbalanced? 2) Did you try Adam with adjusted betas and a lower learning rate (e.g. `learning_rate=0.0001` or even lower)? (Read more about adam [here](http://ruder.io/optimizing-gradient-descent/)). 3) I'd recommend a different architecture, like [RNNs](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/).

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman, Actually the classes are perfectly balanced. There are exactly same number of examples for each class. Yes, I have tried adam with lower learning rates reach up to 10e-6.

Comment: Also: how long from start of training until it puts everything into the same class? It could be so many things. Did you try to add regularizers like [dropout](https://keras.io/layers/core/#dropout) and [batch normalization](https://keras.io/layers/normalization/#batchnormalization)?

Comment: @Anakin, you are right. One label for every 18000 values.

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman, actually most of the times, it starts with an accuracy something like 0.1780 and then it gives the same accuracy at every epoch. Yes, I have tried both of them.

Comment: Shouldn't `train_y ` have `312,18000, 6` dimentions? One hotted? for the `categorical_crossentropy`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192090/discussion-between-andreas-storvik-strauman-and-ozan-yurtsever).

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in defining conv1D layer. From the code, it is evident that you have defined 2 filters and kernel of size 700 however usually around 3 filters and large no of filters are used. Try using this and train without validation split.

```
`model = Sequential() 
 model.add(Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(18000, 3))) 
 model.add(Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu')) 
 model.add(MaxPooling1D(3)) 
 model.add(Conv1D(128, 3, activation='relu')) 
 model.add(Conv1D(128, 3, activation='relu')) 
 model.add(GlobalAveragePooling1D()) 
 model.add(Dropout(0.5)) 
 model.add(Dense(6, activation='softmax')) `
```

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: If I remove GlobalAvaragePoolling1D(), it generated an error. `Error when checking target: expected dense_9 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (312, 6)`